# MySql InnoDB: Alter table > Add primary key: Error "Row size too large"

Tags: mysql, innodb

I am trying to ALTER a MySql Table to add a primary key, the query is very simple, but I get error "Row size too large", how can that be possible?

I did some searches and I have found that some one solved increasing the value of this two settings:

```
innodb_log_file_size=512M
innodb_log_buffer_size=1000M
```

Which I have set to maximum possible, but still getting the same error, which is this:

```
Operation failed: There was an error while applying the SQL script to the database.
Executing:
ALTER TABLE `propdb`.`properties` 
CHANGE COLUMN `ID` `ID` INT(11) NULL ,
ADD PRIMARY KEY (`ID`);


ERROR 1118: Row size too large. The maximum row size for the used table type, not counting BLOBs, is 8126. This includes storage overhead, check the manual. You have to change some columns to TEXT or BLOBs
SQL Statement:
ALTER TABLE `propdb`.`properties` 
CHANGE COLUMN `ID` `ID` INT(11) NULL ,
ADD PRIMARY KEY (`ID`)
```

I am since hours after this, I have searched a lot here and other site but no solution helped me.

I am using XAMPP for Windows 10, recently download so it is a new version.

Comment: which mysql version are you using? see manual for more information https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/column-count-limit.html

Comment: Can you run `SHOW CREATE TABLE propdb.properties` and edit your question above to include the result? The error suggests you have columns whose size totals more than 8KB. The innodb settings you describe are not relevant to the solution.

Comment: @BillKarwin I can't show field names because of sensitive data can be desumed. it has 87 columns, 1 is ID INT (11), all the rest are varchar(45) DEFAULT NULL, 4 of them are text type.

Comment: Please show us the entire `SHOW CREATE TABLE`.  The problem is likely to be with some other index.  What version did you used to have?  What version now?  There have been some default changes.